# Check difference in years

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to check whether the selected date is 2 years (24 months) old in C#. for some reason I am getting the logic in here, brain overloaded. This is my code. How do I check if it is 2 years old?

```
if (dt.AddMonths(-24) < System.DateTime)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are almost there. Assuming `dt` is the date you want to check is more than 2 years old, the do this:

```
if(dt < System.DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-24))
{
  ...
}
```

Running this code today (`21/05/2013`) then the statement would return true when `dt` is `20/05/2011` or earlier. If you want to include `21/05/2011` then use `<=` instead

NOTE: There is also an [`AddYears`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addyears.aspx) method

Answer (score 6):

```
return dt < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2)
```

Comment: `Today` is better than `Now`, but fair play for pointing out the needless if/else (though I suspect the OP code may just be for example purposes... well, I hope it is anyway)

Comment: @musefan: why do you say that `Today` is better than `Now`? `Today` removes the time part, but don't think that's an advantage here.

Comment: Supposedly it's faster, and yes I know we are taking tiny amounts, which I would normal not worry about. But when it comes down to one property over another, I would choose the more efficient one - unless the time is important of course

Answer (score 3):

Instead of [`AddMonths()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx), you can use [`AddYears()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx) which is more understandable in your case;

```
 if(dt < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2))
 {
     return true;
 }
 else
 {
    return false;
 }
```

> Returns a new DateTime that **adds the specified number of years** to the
>   value of this instance

Comment: The other benefit of `AddYears`, and more important the readability probably, is the fact that it takes into consideration leap years.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: Does `AddMonths` not take leap years into consideration? Surely it just Add/Subtracts the month value without even considering the days?

Comment: @musefan, I think you're right. I read the documentation for `AddMonths` again and it states that it does.

Comment: @SonerGönül, looks like `AddMonths` does as well. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You've got it backwards; you're checking whether the date is 2 years in the future.

You want to either subtract 24 months (or 2 years) from `DateTime.Now`, or add 24 months (or 2 years) to `dt`.

Both of these will do what you want:

```
if (dt.AddMonths(24) < DateTime.Now) //or dt.AddYears(2)
```

and

```
if (dt < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-24)) //or DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2)
```

If all you're really doing is returning true or false, there's no need for the if. Simply `return` the result of the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
return dt.AddYears(2) < System.DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: I think the months have to be added to DateTime.Now instead of the date itself

Comment: Withouth the minus you mean...

Comment: @vc74 It can be either way, but if added to the date it needs to be +24 not -24.

Comment: @Servy that's what I meant

Comment: Oops, thanks for the correction. I've now made it `AddYears(2)` instead of `AddMonths(-24)`.